# Php API , POST does not read the username /password I sent via postman

Tags: php, mysql, post

This is the php code

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");

   $response = array();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');


   if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

   $username = $_POST['_username'];
   $password = $_POST['_password'];

   var_dump($_POST);
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role FROM user_details where 
   useremail='$username' and userpassword='$password'");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   $data = $row[0];

   if($data){
      echo $data;
   }

   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

http://localhost/android_login_api/mycon.php?username=m@gmail.com&password=1234

It gives the following error

> Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_api\mycon.php on line  12

I tried the GET, without passing parameters then I can return the values.
But here I am working on a login screen so I need to use POST method to capture the values.

Appreciate your guidance on this 
Using xampp V3.2.4

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing post data by keys **_username** and **_password**

```
$username = $_POST['_username'];
$password = $_POST['_password'];
```

Whereas in postman you are supplying http://localhost/android_login_api/mycon.php?username=m@gmail.com&password=1234 ie **username** and **password**

That is why you are getting **undefined index** error at **line no 12** ie **$username = $_POST['_username'];**

Either change to

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Or change call as

```
http://localhost/android_login_api/mycon.php?_username=m@gmail.com&_password=1234
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually you are doing it the wrong way, API in PHP is not created the way you are doing. Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html)

Modify your code as follows, I have removed other parts

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo('Name: ' . $data->username .'<br />');
echo('Password: ' . $data->password);
?>
```

and from postman

[image]

Comment: Sorry about it. Actually I have changed every thing as you told, still the same issue is there.

Comment: I have updated the answer, I would suggest following the tutorial steps.

Comment: Thank you so much .the tutorial you posted and the updates you have provided helped me a lot to solve the issue I had.